# web worker doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

May someone could tell me why my web worker does not work?
I draw an animated canvas that is run well. But when I resize it via text boxes, it stops running until the JavaScript executed. Now, I create a worker to assume the task of resize the graphic without stopping the movement of canvas. I want it to update the value of the hidden field, by taking the values the text boxes, convert to string, then set the result to the hidden field value. For that I make to files. I mean no JavaScript code in the html markup. the code files are the follow

```
/* Code that will be run by the worker */

function applyChanges(radius, size) {
    return radius + "," + size;
}

/*
    Add an event listener to the worker, this will be called when      
    the worker receives a message from the main page.
*/
this.onmessage = function (event) {
    var data = event.data;

    // Message sent by the worker to the main page.
    postMessage(applyChanges(data.radius, data.size));
}

/* Worker's code */

// Create a new worker
var myWorker = new Worker("C:\applications\bb\scripts\setValues.js");
/*
    Add a event listener to the worker, this will be called whenever the worker posts any message.
*/
myWorker.onmessage = function (event) {
    document.getElementById().value = event.data;
};

// Register events for button.
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function () {
    var circle = document.getElementById("tcircle");
    var square = document.getElementById("tsquare");
    var radius = circle.value;
    var size = square.value;

    // check if those are numerics
    if (!isNaN(radius) && !isNaN(size)) {
        // verify that the won't hide more the 1/4 of the circle.
        if (radius >= size / Math.SQRT2) {
            // since we are going to test scrolling and zooming, we are not going to  set max values of radius and size.

            message = { "tcircle": radius, "tsize": size };

            // Message sent by the main page to the worker.
            myWorker.postMessage(message);

        }
        else {
            alert("The radius must not be less that: size/sqrt(2)");
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("Required numeric type!");
    }
}

// Terminate the worker.
myWorker.terminate();
```

Comment: please indent code 4 spaces so that it formats correctly. you can use the button in the editor

Answer (score 3):

Web Workers are asynchronous JavaScript processing environments that do not have access to their host environment: the DOM. In web workers you can offload intense algorithms, Math computations, but you cannot access form elements, change or access the DOM, and I also believe you cannot spawn ajax requests.

Comment: Thank you Eli. So what can do to update the value of the hidden field without stop the motion of the canvas?

Answer (score 0):

There has been an update to what Chrome allows now that may help with this problem.

Based on this answer, using Chrome you can pass the data back to the worker, then write it back to the canvas, so others may follow, but at least it is a way to continue with your testing.

[Web Workers and Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864756/web-workers-and-canvas/3229118#3229118)

You may want to look at how this demo works to get an idea what you can do with `WebWorker` and `Canvas`.

http://www.robodesign.ro/coding/html5-demo-video-histogram/index-web-worker.html

Comment: Thank you James. The application will run on Blackberry mobile. So my main problem is how to take the values of input text then send those values to the hidden field. Is it a way to do that?

Comment: Why not just stop the webworker when there is a change, then start a new one with the new value.  It will be quick in javascript, so the user shouldn't see any change.

Comment: I am lose. I have examples running. I can't understand what mine doesn't run. I reduce code but nothing. If you don't mine to have a glance on it.

Comment: // worker.js

function applyValues(radius, size) {
    return radius + "," + size;
}

/* 
Add a event listener to the worker, this will
be called when the worker receives a message
from the main page.
*/
this.onmessage = function(event) {
    var data = event.data;
    postMessage(applyValues(data.radius, data.size));
};

Comment: // worker
        function getWebWorkerSupport() {
            return (typeof (Worker) !== "undefined") ? true : false;
        }

        if (getWebWorkerSupport() == true) {
            var radius, size, message;
worker = new Worker("worker.js");

worker.onmessage = function(event) {
alert(event.data);
document.getElementById("hidden").value = event.data;
};

document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
radius = document.getElementById("tcircle").value;
size = document.getElementById("tsquare").value;
message = { 'radius': radius, 'size': size };
worker.postMessage(message);}
}

Comment: @Le_Bedel - Can you add the code to your question, so it can be formatted please.