# DOM input events vs. setTimeout/setInterval order

Tags: javascript, dom, input, dom-events

I have a block of JavaScript code running on my page; let's call it `func1`. It takes several milliseconds to run. While that code is running, the user may click, move the mouse, enter some keyboard input, etc. I have another block of code, `func2`, that I want to run after all of those queued-up input events have resolved. That is, I want to ensure the order:

1. `func1`
2. All handlers bound to input events that occurred while `func1` was running
3. `func2`

My question is: **Is calling `setTimeout func2, 0` at the end of `func1` sufficient to guarantee this ordering, across all modern browsers?** What if that line came at the beginning of `func1`—what order should I expect in that case?

Please back up your answers with either references to the relevant specs, or test cases.

**Update:** It turns out that no, it's not sufficient. What I failed to realize in my original question was that input events aren't even *added* to the queue until the current code block has been executed. So if I write

```
// time-consuming loop...
setTimeout func2, 0
```

then only *after* that `setTimeout` is run will any input events (clicks, etc.) that occurred during the time-consuming loop be queued. (To test this, note that if you remove, say, an `onclick` callback immediately *after* the time-consuming loop, then clicks that happened during the loop won't trigger that callback.) So `func2` is queued first and takes precedence.

Setting a timeout of `1` seemed to work around the issue in Chrome and Safari, but in Firefox, I saw input events resolving after timeouts as high as `80` (!). So a purely time-based approach clearly isn't going to do what I want.

Nor is it sufficient to simply wrap one `setTimeout ... 0` inside of another. (I'd hoped that the first timeout would fire after the input events queued, and the second would fire after they resolved. No such luck.) Nor did adding a third, or a fourth, level of nesting suffice (see Update 2 below).

So if anyone has a way of achieving what I described (other than setting a timeout of 90+ milliseconds), I'd be very grateful. Or is this simply impossible with the current JavaScript event model?

Here's my latest JSFiddle testbed: http://jsfiddle.net/EJNSu/7/

**Update 2:** A partial workaround is to nest `func2` inside of two timeouts, removing all input event handlers in the first timeout. However, this has the unfortunate side effect of causing some—or even all—input events that occurred during `func1` to fail to resolve. (Head to http://jsfiddle.net/EJNSu/10/ and try rapidly clicking the link several times to observe this behavior. How many clicks does the alert tell you that you had?) So this, again, surprises me; I wouldn't think that calling `setTimeout func2, 0`, where `func2` sets `onclick` to `null`, could prevent that callback from being run in response to a click that happened a full second ago. I want to ensure that all input events fire, but that my function fires after them.

**Update 3:** I posted my answer below after playing with this testbed, which is illuminating: http://jsfiddle.net/TrevorBurnham/uJxQB/

Move the mouse over the box (triggering a 1-second blocking loop), then click multiple times. After the loop, all the clicks you performed play out: The top box's `click` handler flips it under the other box, which then receives the next `click`, and so on. The timeout triggered in the `mouseenter` callback does not consistently occur after the click events, and the time it takes for the click events to occur varies wildly across browsers even on the same hardware and OS. (Another odd thing this experiment turned up: I sometimes get multiple jQuery `mouseenter` events even when I move the mouse steadily into the box. Not sure what's going on there.)

Comment: I think the order is not guaranteed in your case. I have not heard about event handling priorities. I think you should handle an event queue before doing *setTimeout* if you like situation is obvious. Did you search in google: "javascript event queue"?

Comment: For example, for Opera: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/timing-and-synchronization-in-javascript/

Comment: @sergzach But how would I "handle an event queue before doing `setTimeout`"? As far as I know, there's no way to ask from an `onclick` callback or the like, "Are any more DOM events in line to fire after this one?"

Comment: The Opera article strongly suggests to me that the answer to me question is "yes," but I'd like to see something more authoritative.

Comment: @jessegavin Here's a test case: https://gist.github.com/1038695

Comment: Why not use setTimeout(func2, 50) at the end of func1, or don't you want to waste those 50ms.

Comment: @Gerben Right, I don't want to waste 50ms. Also, even 50ms turned out not to be enough in Firefox—and that's on a fast system, with just a single `click` event. I want to be *sure* that the input events resolve first.

Comment: @Fritz: I hate when that happens ^_^

Comment: The multiple `mouseenter` events is probably because you are swapping the `z-index` of the blue box and the red box. When they swap positions your mouse is entering the box that has been moved to the top. If supporting IE < 10 is still important it [won't be an option](http://caniuse.com/#search=requestanimationframe), but you might want to look into using [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead of `setTimeout` now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point, I'm prepared to say that, regrettably, **there is no solution to this problem** that will work under all browsers, in every scenario, every time. In a nutshell: If you run a JavaScript function, there's no way to reliably distinguish between input events that the user triggered *during* that time and those the user triggered *afterward*. This has interesting implications for JS developers, especially those working with interactive canvases.

My mental model of how JS input events work was off the mark. I'd thought that it went

1. The user clicks a DOM element while code is running
2. If that element has a `click` event handler, the callback is queued
3. When all blocking code has executed, the callback is run

However, my experiments, and those contributed by Wladimir Palant (thanks, Wladimir) show that the correct model is

1. The user clicks a DOM element while code is running
2. The browser captures the coordinates, etc. of the click
3. Some time after all blocking code has executed, the browser checks which DOM element is at those coordinates, then runs the callback (if any)

I say "some time after" because different browsers seem to have very different behaviors for this—in Chrome for Mac, I can set a `setTimeout func2, 0` at the end of my blocking code and expect `func2` to run after the click callbacks (which run only 1-3ms after the blocking code finished); but in Firefox, the timeout always resolves first, and the click callbacks typically happen ~40ms after the blocking code finished executing. This behavior is apparently beyond the purview of any JS or DOM spec. As John Resig put it in his classic [How JavaScript Timers Work](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/):

> When an asynchronous event occurs (like a mouse click, a timer firing, or an XMLHttpRequest completing) it gets queued up to be executed later (*how this queueing actually occurs surely varies from browser-to-browser*, so consider this to be a simplification).

(Emphasis mine.)

So what does this mean from a practical standpoint? This is a non-issue as the execution time of blocking code approaches 0. Which means that this problem is yet another reason to hew to that old advice: **Break up your JS operations into small chunks to avoid blocking the thread.**

Web workers, as Useless Code suggested, are even better when you can use them—but be aware that you're foregoing [compatibility with Internet Explorer and all major mobile browsers](http://caniuse.com/webworkers).

Finally, I hope browser-makers will move forward on standardizing input events in the future. This is one of [many quirks in that area](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html). I hope Chrome will lead the way to the future: excellent thread isolation, low event latency, and relatively consistent queueing behavior. A web developer can dream, can't he?

Comment: Please keep in mind that the blocking JavaScript code could change event handlers or the DOM structure of the document. Also, there can be event listeners on different levels of the document, some of which might or might not be reached depending on whether any listener calls `stopPropagation()`. So your simple mental model cannot work.

Comment: But you can change #2 into "The click event is queued to be processed later" and #3 into "When all blocking code has executed the queued events are processed (hit target determined, appropriate listeners triggered)". With the remark "Timeouts go into the same queue and are guaranteed to run after the events are processed if these events were added to the queue before the timeout". That matches the behavior of Firefox on Windows, too bad that it is apparently different on Mac.

Comment: I think we're saying the same thing in different words. When you say "The click event is queued to be processed later," that doesn't sound right to me, because when I hear the words "click event," I think of particular arguments being passed to a particular callback; but as you well know, neither the arguments nor the callback are determined until after #3. (Even `e.timeStamp`, in browsers that support it, matches the time when the first callback was called, not the time that the user clicked something.)

Comment: That's because Firefox (and other browsers probably similarly) have a distinction between "native events" and "DOM events". A DOM event is what event listeners see and it isn't created until the event processing starts. A native event on the other hand isn't much more than what the OS supplies.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are on the wrong track with your experiments. One problem is of course that you are fighting different message loop implementations here. The other (the one you didn't recognize it seems) is different double click handling. If you click the link twice you won't get two `click` events in MSIE - it's rather one `click` event and a `dblclick` event (for you that looks like the second click was "swallowed"). All other browsers seem to generate two `click` events and a `dblclick` event in this scenario. So you need to handle `dblclick` events as well.

As message loops go, Firefox should be easiest to handle. From all I know, Firefox adds messages to the queue even when JavaScript code is running. So a simple `setTimeout(..., 0)` is sufficient to run code after the messages are processed. You should refrain from hiding the link after `func1()` is done however - at this point clicks aren't processed yet and they won't trigger event handlers on a hidden element. Note that even a zero timeout doesn't get added to the queue immediately, current Firefox versions have 4 milliseconds as the lowest possible timeout value.

MSIE is similar, only that there you need to handle `dblclick` events as I mentioned before. Opera seems to work like that as well but it doesn't like it if you don't call `event.preventDefault()` (or return `false` from the event handler which is essentially the same thing).

Chrome however seems to add the timeout to the queue first and only add incoming messages after that. Nesting two timeouts (with zero timeout value) seems to do the job here.

The only browser where I cannot make things work reliably is Safari (version 4.0 on Windows). The scheduling of messages seems random there, looks like timers there execute on a different thread and can push messages into the message queue at random times. In the end you probably have to accept that your code might not get interrupted on the first occasion and the user might have to wait a second longer.

Here is my adaptation of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/KBFqn/7/

Comment: On Firefox 5 for Mac, no matter how many times I click during the loop in your example, I get 0-2 interrupts. So I'm afraid I can't accept this as a solution. The point about double-clicking is a good one, though. Perhaps we could clarify matters by testing with keyboard events instead?

Comment: @Trevor Burnham: I see, message queue handling in Firefox on Mac must be different then (all the testing above happened on Windows). Too bad.

Comment: @Trevor Burnham: I switched to `keypress` handling in http://jsfiddle.net/KBFqn/8/ and it seems to work correctly for me in all browsers, even in Safari. Click the link and then press some key several times. Looks like browsers treat keyboard events differently from mouse events.

Comment: On Mac: In Chrome, all `keypress`es seem to register before the timeout. In Safari 5, the results are inconsistent (I'll press 6 keys and 2-4 will register). In Firefox 5, results are worse (I'll press 6 keys and 0-2 will register). I'd love to test this on Windows/Linux, because it's entirely possible that the way the OS handles input events makes a big difference here.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you have a long-running function but you don't want to block the UI while it is running?  After the long-running function is done you then want to run another function?

If so instead of using timeouts or intervals you might want to use [Web Workers](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/complete/workers.html) instead.  All modern browsers including IE9 should support Web Workers.

I threw together an [example page](http://www.uselesscode.org/examples/stackoverflow/6391536/test.html) (couldn't put it on jsfiddle since Web Workers rely on an external .js file that has to be hosted on the same origin).

If you click A, B, C or D a message will be logged on the right.  When you press start a Web Worker starts processing for 3 seconds. Any clicks during those 3 seconds will be immediately logged.

The important parts of the code are here:

**func1.js** The code that runs inside the Web Worker

```
onmessage = function (e) {
    var result,
    data = e.data, // get the data passed in when this worker was called
                   // data now contains the JS literal {theData: 'to be processed by func1'}
    startTime;
    // wait for a second
    startTime = (new Date).getTime();
    while ((new Date).getTime() - startTime < 1000) {
        continue;
    }
    result = 42;
    // return our result
    postMessage(result);
}
```

The code that invokes the Web Worker:

```
var worker = new Worker("func1.js");
// this is the callback which will fire when "func1.js" is done executing
worker.onmessage = function(event) {
    log('Func1 finished');
    func2();
};

worker.onerror = function(error) {
    throw error;
};

// send some data to be processed
log('Firing Func1');
worker.postMessage({theData: 'to be processed by func1'});
```

Comment: Web Workers are a good suggestion, but 1) not universally supported (e.g. they're nowhere to be found in IE<9) and 2) [can't be used for drawing on the canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864756/web-workers-and-canvas), which was the use case I had in mind when posting this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dispatchEvent` with a custom event name at the end of your function. This won't work on IE, but is still possible; just use `fireEvent` instead.

Take a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/NsY9V/

Click "start the long run", and click on the textbox and type in it. Voilà!

Comment: Not sure how that helps, minitech. I created a fork [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fzFan/) that shows the value of the `input` element as of `afterRun`; I get the same value as before the `longRun` loop. Can you make `afterRun` execute after the user input has been processed?

Comment: @Trevor: Hm... in that case, what *exactly* is the situation? Is the user going to be typing? Is it acceptable to change the focus? What's the entire situation?

Comment: The problem arose form my work with canvas. Let's say it takes 250ms to render a canvas. I want the user's `click` and `mousemove` events during that period to reflect the state that was visible during those 250ms, but I want all `click` and `mousemove` events afterward to reflect the newly drawn state. So I want my `updateState` function to fire after all input that occurred during the canvas rendering period has resolved, but before any further input occurs. Turns out that's a challenge.

Comment: @Trevor: Then you can use a state variable. Editing answer.

Comment: Won't work. `isRunning` will *definitely* be false before any of the input events fire.

Comment: @Trevor: Oops, not quite thinking straight. Sorry.

Comment: @minitech: Events dispatched by `dispatchEvent()` aren't added to the message queue, instead they are processed synchronously. So in your example `afterRun()` will be called before `dispatchEvent()` returns - same as if you call `afterRun()` directly. Really adding messages to the queue is possible with `window.postMessage()` (per HTML5 spec) but I don't think it will have an advantage over timeouts here.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the event handlers check to see if a flag is set by `func1`; if so queue `func2` if not already queued.

This may either be elegant or ugly depending on the specializedness of `func2`. (Actually it's probably just ugly.) If you choose this approach, you need some way to hook events, or alternatively your own `bindEvent(event,handler,...)` function which wraps the handler and binds the wrapped handler.

The correctness of this approach depends on all the events during `func1` being queued at the same time. If this is not the case, you can either make `func2` idempotent, or (depending on the semantics of `func2`) put an ugly "cannot be called again for N milliseconds" lock on it.

Comment: Suppose the user clicked 10 times during `func1`. It would be easy to add `if (!h) h = setTimeout(func2, 0)` to the `click` callback, but could I be sure that `func2` wouldn't fire until after the other 9 clicks (and perhaps other input events) have been resolved?

Comment: Ah, of course, re-queueing it in every input handler (`clearTimeout` plus `setTimeout`) does work: http://jsfiddle.net/EJNSu/11/ I'll accept this answer if no one has a more elegant solution.

Comment: Hmm, I spoke too soon. The example above fails (under Firefox 5 for Mac) if I move the `alert` code out of the arbitrary 500ms timeout into `func2`—which means that the clicks are actually firing after `func2`. See http://jsfiddle.net/TrevorBurnham/j8kVY/

Answer (score 0):

please describe better you scenario.

What you need do

some time ago i need do something how that was so i build an simple javascript's routine across serialize async call in one sync call. maybe you could used that added one variant

for example that let me show how that work

first register all async or sync routines 
second register end callback
third register call's to routines with yours parameters
fourth thrown process

in your case it neccesary added one call routine and that routine should be UoW of user actions. 
Now the main problem is not call to routine in and order of execution if not track changes done by the user

first register all async or sync routines 
second register end callback
third register call's to routines with yours paramter
  --register your first routine
  --register BlockUi //maybe for not accept more changes in the view
  --register UiWriter // UoW of change done by user
  --register you last routine
fourth thrown process

in real code that is one call dummy's function

function Should_Can_Serializer_calls()
{
  RegisterMethods(model);
  model.Queue.BeginUnitProcess(); //clear stack of execution, y others
  model.Queue.AddEndMethod(SucessfullEnd);  // callback to end routine
  model.AbstractCall("func1",1,"edu",15,""); //set routine how first to execute
  model.AbstractCall("BlockUi"); //track changes and user's actions
  model.AbstractCall("UiWork"); //track changes and user's actions
  model.AbstractCall("func2","VALUE"); //set second routine for execute
  model.Process(); //throw call
}

Now the methods should be async for themselves for this you could use that library http://devedge-temp.mozilla.org/toolbox/examples/2003/CCallWrapper/index_en.html

so, what do you want do?