# Drawing in workers

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, web-worker

I am trying to draw in a web worker using html5 canvas.  The worker doesn't have access to the DOM so I can't draw on a canvas from the web worker.  [This other stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864756/web-workers-and-canvas) suggests I can manipulate the ImageData from the worker.

Am I limiting to performing raw pixel manipulation on the ImageData item or can I perform things like drawBezzierCurve() on it?  Or maybe there is a library to manipulate this type of data.

Comment: Look at http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/WorkerFountains/Default.html which is a demo from Microsoft of something similar to what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the best you can do is get the `<canvas>` raw [`imageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/ImageData) and pass the `imageData` back and forth between the web worker.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call any `<canvas>` functions from web workers currently. Also, pixel manipulation is limited because you most likely need to use `postMessage()` to push forth and back whole canvas data once, meaning a lot of data copying slowing down it.

This all sucks greatly.