# Is delegating JSON.parse to web worker worthwile (in Chrome Extension/FF Addon)?

Tags: json, firefox, google-chrome, web-worker

I am writing a Chrome Extension which stores great deal of data in browser's localStorage and parses it on every page load. Now as the size of data increases, page load time/performance starts degrading. So I thought delegating the parsing to a web worker. But I am doubtful if it is worthwile. What I can do is pass my string to be parsed to worker like this.

```
worker.postMessage(localStorage['myObj']);
```

And I plan to parse this string into JSON and send it back to the main thread, like so

```
worker.onMessage(function(myObj){
    //Then Play around with my object here.
});
```

But as I googled on the performance aspect of this method, including message posting and listening overheads, and the fact that some browser's don't allow sending JSON objects in the message and some serialize it automatically while sending, I doubt if this method is worthwile.

Since my app is just a Chrome Extension and also a Firefox Addon, I am concerned with just these two browsers. Can anyone suggest me if this method is suitable for these two browsers?

Comment: Have you tried setting up a benchmark for this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The currently-accepted answer is simply incorrect. It's entirely feasible to do what you asked about, example below.

Whether it's **worth** doing is something you'll have to check with real data in your real scenario. There's overhead associated with sending the JSON text to the worker and having it send back the parsed result (which may well involve some under-the-covers serialization, though it's probably not JSON), and modern browsers parse JSON very quickly.

I suspect the overhead isn't worth it, but perhaps on huge JSON strings, if the browser's native serialization mechanism is either much faster than JSON or takes place on a thread other than the main UI thread, perhaps it could be.

---

Example of using a worker to parse JSON:

```js
// This stands in for 'worker.js':
var blob = new Blob([
  'this.onmessage = function(message) {\n' +
    'postMessage(JSON.parse(message.data));\n' +
  '};'
  ], { type: "text/javascript" });
var workerUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

// Main script:
var w = new Worker(workerUrl/*"worker.js"*/);
w.onmessage = function(message) {
    display("Got response: typeof message.data: " + typeof message.data);
    display("message.data.for = " + message.data.foo);
};

display('Posting JSON \'{"foo":"bar"}\' to worker');
w.postMessage('{"foo":"bar"}');

function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = String(msg);
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

Result:

```
Posting JSON '{"foo":"bar"}' to worker
Got response: typeof message.data: object
message.data.for = bar
```

Answer (score 1):

Only strings, not objects, can be passed to and from WebWorkers. If you parse a string into a JSON object within a WebWorker, you will need to stringify the object and then reparse it when passing it from the worker to your main script. Obviously, this will cause the JSON to be double-parsed unnecessarily and so is a bad idea.

**2017 Update**: More than just strings are allowed now. See some of the (much newer) answers and comments for reference.

Comment: *"Only strings, not objects, can be passed to and from WebWorkers..."* That's incorrect, you can send arbitrary data to and from web workers, within limits. Plain JavaScript object graphs are just fine. (More interesting objects, like canvas data, [were added circa 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864756/web-workers-and-canvas).) So in theory you could send the JSON string to the worker, have it parse it, and then have it send back the parsed result. I can't imagine it's remotely worth it, but you can do it.

Comment: When WebWorkers were first introduced, they passed around strings. That improved with Chrome 13 (?). WebWorkers have matured in the 5 years since this question was asked.

Comment: Again: Non-string data was introduced in at least 2010 (and supported in Chrome 6), three years prior to this answer. (And yes, sure, they've also moved on since.)

Comment: Not all browsers supported non-string data until later.