# Html5 canvas map application / canvas per tile vs single canvas for a layer

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, dictionary

We are creating a canvas map applicaiton and we wonder which approach is better than the other; craeting canvases for every single tile of a layer or creating a single canvas.

If we use canvas per tile option, we will be able to;

- Doing fade animations on pan effect for every single tile,
- On zoom-out, when layer size is smaller than screen size, We will
  draw smaller areas (Only 2-3 small canvases for example).

But;

- There will be much more than one context and more draw operations.
- (I think)More memory usage.

So we couldnt decide which option to choose. Performence is very important for us, because we are working with big data. But also we care about animations like pan and zoom with css3. What do you suggest?

Comment: How about a third proposition? A single canvas with multi-threading enabled. Keyword: [Web Workers](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp). See also [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864756/web-workers-and-canvas). A google search leads to an [MSDN article on performance improvements of a canvas render using WebWorkers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2012/09/20/using-web-workers-to-improve-performance-of-image-manipulation.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! It will really help about performance I think. I'll try it and write you back if I get an improvemnt on performence.

Comment: @Derija93 From the article you link to: "A important point to note is that on recent computers the difference can be thin or even in favor of the code without workers. The overhead of the memory copy must be balanced by a complex code used by the workers. "

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware Well, JavaScript was never intended to be a multi-threaded script language. There really isn't an ideal solution to this problem, each has its advantages and downdraws. Using workers indeed probably results in a highly complex code... Like I said, it's just a proposition. ;)

Comment: @Derija93 I know and the idea is excellent :-) I just point it out as Web Workers unfortunately seem to have limited benefits compared to the drafted potential (too much restriction passing data IMHO).

Comment: @HalilIbrahim you could also consider this library: http://leafletjs.com/

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware Thanks, I noticed that, that is the library http://www.giscloud.com/ uses. And I know that they are using muliple canvases for a layer. But when 15 or more layers come up, It crashes on rendering. I've tried it on all browsers. Maybe it is because of bad implemantation.

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware on the link below, if you make all layers shown and then try to zoom in and out, it crashes. http://www.giscloud.com/map/137021/oc-landbase

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware That issue actually originates in the fact that JavaScript was never designed to be multithreaded. The WebWorkers are simply a hackish workaround. Each worker runs in a separate thread of the JS engine. But since the engine is single-threaded, there is no way to share data directly. Thus the data you pass isn't the real data. It is stringified, then sent to the worker which ultimately deserializes it to a plain object. It's just a copy with great limits... no circular reference, no constructors, etc. (Just sharing information as I know it. No guarantee for correctness. ;) )

Answer (score 0):

For performence consideration, single canvas for a layer is recommended in most cases include the animations like pan and zoom(if it is not must be implemented by css3). And some projects listed follow may be helpful to you:
 1. https://github.com/dfacts/Slippy-Map-On-Canvas
 2. https://github.com/zynga/scroller