# Decode JPEG in web worker

Tags: javascript, jpeg, web-worker, emscripten

How can I decode a JPEG in a web worker to get access to the pixel data, without including code (written by myself or 3rd party) to decode the JPEG, but using a built-in browser API.

---

I understand that I can render a JPEG to a canvas in the main thread, read off the pixel data, and pass it to the worker if that's where I want it, but I am specifically investigating the possibilities of decoding the JPEG in the worker.

I also understand that I can use a third party library, but I am wondering if there is anything built into browsers that can do this, since it seems strange to have to send code that duplicates browser ability.

Comment: You can use some library like this: https://github.com/notmasteryet/jpgjs

Comment: What have you tried so far? JPEG format is documented and there are libraries that can handle the issue - you can get those by a google search.

Comment: @Tomáš understood that there are libraries, but wondering if there is a way using a built in API in a worker. I have added this point to the question.

Comment: The only image processing API I'm aware of is `canvas` and that has already been asked and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1864756/607407

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr:** [No](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1864774/607407).

After your edit, the question whether you can use built-in API (which is only `canvas` at this moment) the answer is no. You cannot create `HTMLElement`s, including `canvas` in web workers because they are GUI components and most GUI frameworks refuse to allow GUI component instantiation outside GUI thread.

This is of course quite unfortunate, it means there's no way to use native API (`CanvasRenderingContext2D`) to do any image operations at all.

Your question as I answer it now was already asked and answered: [Web Workers and Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1864756/607407)

I would suggest favoriting that question for updates - I hope as well that in future image processing will be possible in web workers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just to clarify, that question isn't exactly what I'm asking... they asked if you can access canvas from a web worker, which if possible would give *a* browser API where you can decode a JPEG. I was asking (knowing that you can't access canvas), if there is *any* browser API available in a worker where you can decode a JPEG.

Comment: The answer remains no. The only image manipulation APIs in browsers can be accessed through `canvas.getContext`. If you have read more thoroughly through the answers, you'd see [one explicitly mentioning future possibilities of image manipulation API in web workers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1864774/607407). But now, the answer is no, and you can take details in my answer as a bonus to that answer.

Comment: I also explicitly stated that canvas is only image manipulation API I'm aware of, so I don't understand why you further ask *if there is any browser API available in a worker where you can decode a JPEG* - I think I couldn't be more clear that there is no such API. If you're about to ask the same question over again you're just not gonna get a different answer, sorry.

Comment: I don't think I did further ask...  "Your question as I answer it now was already asked and answered" suggested to me that you were saying [Web Workers and Canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1864756/1319998) and this were the same question. I was claiming that they are different questions. I suspect I was nitpicking, which now that I think about it, probably wasn't very constructive.

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica Hello, I answered over in the "Web Workers and Canvas" question that you linked how nowadays the canvas can be used inside a web worker. Given that canvas-in-worker is now possible (in some browsers), the question is now: what canvas APIs would we call to decode a JPG image (assuming we have a binary typed array containing the image data for example)?

Comment: I'm not aware of any option that does not involve main thread. Normally, you use `<img>` to draw it on canvas from any format supported by the browser. But `<img>` is still not available in worker, so unless you write JPEG parser yourself, the code responsible for parsing images is still not available in worker. However passing the parsed image from main thread to worker is a cheap operation. I'll come back to this if I learn more.